# Validator - OOP

Tags: php, oop

I have a problem with the code and don't know what to do.
I used this

`$validate = new OOP_Validate;`

`$validate->addValidator(new OOP_Validate_Int());`

`if($validate->isValid('test')) echo 'TRUE';`

and show me error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to OOP_Validate::addValidator() must implement interface OOP_Validate_Interface, instance of OOP_Validate_Int given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameV\index.php on line 21 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameV\library\OOP\Validate.php on line 37
```

AddValidator:

```
public function addValidator(OOP_Validate_Interface $validator, $breakChain = false){
    $this->_validators[] = array(
        'Name'     =>  $validator,
        'Break'    =>  $breakChain,
    );
    return $this;   
}
```

Interface:

```
interface OOP_Validate_Interface {

    public function isValid($value);
    public function getMessage();

}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: does `OOP_Validate_Int` implement `OOP_Validate_Interface`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message explains, the `addValidator` method requires that the first argument passed to it implements the interface called `OOP_Validate_Interface`.

```
$validate->addValidator(new OOP_Validate_Int() /* <-- this argument must implement OOP_Validate_Interface */);
```

Check your code and change the class declaration for `OOP_Validate_Int` to be:

```
class OOP_Validate_Int implements OOP_Validate_Interface
{

    /* 
       Then ensure that all the methods required by OOP_Validate_Interface
       are defined in this class.
    */

}
```

For more info, check the [Object Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) section in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that method addValidator accepts the first parameter of type OOP_Validator_Interface but You pass it an instance of OPP_Validate_Int() here: `$validate->addValidator(new OOP_Validate_Int());`.

I suggest not to explicitly retype the first argument of addValidator() (if it is not part of some framework) or in other hand a class OOP_Validate_Int must implement the OOP_Validator_Interface: `class OOP_Validate_Int implements OOP_Validator_Interface { .. }`.